# iOS app for a Cloud Storage Service rejected (for not providing In App Purchase for subscription)

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

We are a startup that provides cloud storage ([www.zapdrive.com](http://www.zapdrive.com)). Our iOS app was rejected, and the reason given was the clauses 11.12 of the App Store Review Guidelines, which specifically says:

> "Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the
>   same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set
>   forth in the Developer Program License Agreement."

Please note that we are not offering any subscription from within the App. We do not have any links or buttons in the App that take the user to any external website, whatsoever. It is a very basic app, that lets the users view their files stored in "ZapDrive". To see what the app looks like, you can see it in the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zapdrive.android)

One thing that we see could be close to a violation of the above rule is, on the first page of the App (which is the login screen), we have a text that says:

```
"Don't have a ZapDrive Account? Go to www.zapdrive.com to sign up for a FREE account"
```

However, the above-mentioned line is just plain text, and does not "link" to the actuak website.

Also, the rejection notice says:

> While your app maybe be intended to enhance the experience of your
>   existing subscribers, with the exception of the content specified in
>   Guideline 11.14, if the subscribed product is used within the app, the
>   subscription must be offered in the app using IAP.

Please not that we are not selling any content, or offering a subscription to any content. The users already own the content, and they copy it into their "ZapDrive". The app lets them view/stream the said content.

Although, Apple says that just because other apps are doing this, doesn't mean you can do it too. Still, a lot of other apps (DropBox, Google Drive, Box etc) offer subscriptions, but do not offer IAP.

Can someone please tell us, how are we violating the App Store Guidelines? And what can we do to make it compatible? Is it the text on the login screen that's causing this violation?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Please give an answer here if so.

Comment: another one of those people who asks a question, figures out the answer and never returns to SO to give information back. Thanks user1721616 for being part of the community!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the link. Does the kindle app have a link in their app? Does Dropbox? I don't think so... Take out the link and resubmit and see what happens. Or you can ask apple for more details.

Comment: It is not a link, it is just plain text. This is what 11.14 specifically says "as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content". Do you think website name written in plain text counts as a "button or external link"?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me... That's what I was saying does dropbox/kindle have just a plain text link anywhere to their site? I don't think so...

Comment: I am still waiting to hear back from them. I can see they accessed my website/app again today, so they are reviewing it again. I am waiting for a verdict.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a programming one; there's no better place to ask this than Apple themselves. All iTunesConnect rejections have a corresponding textbox you can communicate with them specifically about that rejection ticket.

Comment: I already did communicate with them, and am waiting for an answer. I just thought I would get some answers from the community and start working on changes (given the time taken by Apple to reply), since we are holding back the release of our service just because of the iOS app. Also, if this is not a programming related question, why does StackOverflow have "app-store" and "appstore-approval" tags. I guess, this counts as a programming question.

Comment: While I may be wrong in saying this is not programming question, the "app-store" tags are there mostly for questions about app binary, provisioning, etc.; but I digress. I work for a business that relies on mobile apps too, and I do understand how critical delays like these are. But no matter what answers or experiences we share here, you have to remember that existing apps (like Dropbox) in the AppStore don't set a precedence for new apps. It's still best to clear this up with Apple themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I know Apple is the ultimate authority. I was just wondering maybe my app has a widely known problem that I was missing, and start on fixing it. Anyways I have already written to them, explaining everything. It does not make sense paying Apple 30% for just making the phone that some of my clients use.